# cordova splashscreen only show me the default one and the default android icon

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, cordova-3

I try to add the splashcreen to my android and ios build. For ios all is working fine. But for android all time i build, all time its just show me the default icon and splashscreen....

here is my config.xml

```
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true"/>
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true"/>
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="4000"/>
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="0"/>
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <icon src="res/screen/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="res/screen/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="res/screen/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="res/screen/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="res/screen/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="res/screen/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <icon src="res/screen/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" height="57"/>
    <icon src="res/screen/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114"/>
    <icon src="res/screen/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40"/>
    <icon src="res/screen/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80"/>
    <icon src="res/screen/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
    <icon src="res/screen/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50"/>
    <icon src="res/screen/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100"/>
    <icon src="res/screen/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60"/>
    <icon src="res/screen/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
    <icon src="res/screen/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180"/>
    <icon src="res/screen/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72"/>
    <icon src="res/screen/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144"/>
    <icon src="res/screen/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76"/>
    <icon src="res/screen/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152"/>
    <icon src="res/screen/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" height="167"/>
    <icon src="res/screen/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29"/>
    <icon src="res/screen/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58"/>
    <icon src="res/screen/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" height="87"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" height="1242"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" height="1536"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" height="768"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
<chcp>
    <config-file url="http://localhost:31284/chcp.json" />
    <local-development enabled="true" />
</chcp>
<icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.2.0" />
<plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugins-keyboard.git" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git" />
```

i have the files like this

res/
- screen/
------android/
------ios/

All is working fine for ios but for android not... if someone can help me thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Update to the latest version of the android platform.

```
cordova platform update android@6.1.0
```

Note: the `@6.1.0` is important, since otherwise version 6.0.0 will be installed and your problems will not be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Resources are cached on your computer, so you can delete them.

Try removing the whole folder (including icons and splashes):

`resources/android/splash`

`resources/ios/splash`

And then ran:

`ionic resources`

Another common error when generating the resources is that it is the splash.png dimension problem. The Photoshop Splash template provided from Ionic generates a 2732x2732 px image. But for some reason, the Ionic server doesn't like it at all. Try resizing and after run the following command again:

`ionic resources`

Hope it helps.

Greetings from Argentina.